# JavaFX 60 fps frame rate cap doesn't work

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX animation which uses the `AnimationTimer()` class. It should work at 60 fps by default, according to all possible sources. However, on my laptop it refreshes at much higher rates: 300 - 700, depending on the window size. I use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, and the Oracle JDK8 on Manjaro Linux GNOME Edition. I've already given a try to other JDKs - still the same situation. It behaves as if the JVM option `javafx.animation.fullspeed` was set true, but it's not. Same happens on a different machine, also running Manjaro GNOME edition.

I tried (undocumented) JVM options:

`javafx.animation.fullspeed=false | true`

`javafx.animation.framerate=value`

`javafx.animation.pulse=value`

They change nothing, even if `Settings.get(key)` returns values as set.

On another, Windows 10-powered computer, FPS behaves correctly: keeps 60 value on default/none VM options, runs full speed when `javafx.animation.fullspeed=true`, as well on Windows, as on Manjaro / VirtualBox.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327853/crazy-javafx-frame-rate-any-ideas and the comments below it.

Comment: Here is the link to the bug report James_D mentioned above. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181764 But the problem is that this bug was rejected because the JavaFX team could not reproduce it. So this seems to be a very specific setup which triggers this bug.

Comment: Thank you @James_D, the workaround resolves the issue very well. I'll add a snippet to the question above. I wouldn't have found the solution ever on my own.

Comment: You can [self-answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it's better than editing the question and putting the solution in the question.

Comment: @jewelsea - I wasn't sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Sample solution thanks to the comment posted by @James_D and the following:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //must be set before launching the Main class
        System.setProperty("quantum.multithreaded", "false");

        Application.launch(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please read comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327853/crazy-javafx-frame-rate-any-ideas) to learn more.

Furthermore: this may be a dual graphics related issue. Forcing use of the secondary graphics like `# optirun ./idea.sh` resolves it, too. However, in the production version I think it would be better to set `quantum.multithreaded` false.

Comment: Just found out my Ubuntu 17.04 with Java 1.8.0..131 was running at 2500fps... No wonder the CPU was busy.

Comment: My app on Manjaro Linux used to use 12 - 15% of the processor, now uses 1 - 2%. Also CPU temperature got back to stable 45 degrees.